# What specialist I need to have in the office to handle CiviCRM daily?

Tags: civimember, civireport

I need to define a job description for a role, that will work with CiviCRM database daily: update member accounts, generate reports, track memberships, send mailings.

Does CiviCRM require any specific set of system admin skills or can any entry-level clerk handle daily tasks in CiviCRM?

In my case, CiviCRM is integrated with Drupal.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!  The tasks you list are all user-level tasks handled through the browser UI and do not need any system admin skills.

You will also need someone to take care of upgrades for CiviCRM core and extension and Drupal core and modules and possibly operating system upgrades.  Depending on your hosting arrangements, those may be taken care of as part of the hosting, or by a third party providing CiviCRM support.

Comment: I agree with Aidan, no special skills needed for the daily data entry. And you can pay your host to do the maintenance for you.

Comment: Aidan, Iowa Boy, thanks - that is helpful. Great to have this community as a resource on Civi